Missing result for "expect_column_values_to_be_of_type" in Great expectations
This is my rule:
rule = {
                        "rule_name": "expect_column_values_to_be_of_type",
                        "parameters": [
                            {
                                "column": column,
                                "type_": column_type.capitalize() + "Type",
                                "result_format" : {"result_format": "COMPLETE"}
                            }
                        ]
                    }

but I am getting just this result:
{
      "success": true,
      "expectation_config": {
        "expectation_type": "expect_column_values_to_be_of_type",
        "kwargs": {
          "column": "id",
          "type_": "IntegerType",
          "batch_id": "my_spark_in_memory_datasource_poc-poc"
        },
        "meta": {}
      },
      "result": {
        "observed_value": "IntegerType"
      },
      "meta": {},
      "exception_info": {
        "raised_exception": false,
        "exception_traceback": null,
        "exception_message": null
      }
    }

I could not get the element_count,partial_unexpected_list, partial_unexpected_counts. In this part:
 "result": {
        "observed_value": "IntegerType"
      }

First I did not use "result_format" : {"result_format": "COMPLETE"}, I am using now but still, I could not get proper result just for "expect_column_values_to_be_of_type" rule. other rules are OK either with result_format or without it.
what can be missing in my configuration?
